# How to get dynamic members from Dynamic View in C# Object?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

How do I get **dynamic members values** from Dynamic View in C# Object.

Code :

```
var db = Db.Profiles;

var buyingCompanies =
    ((SimpleQuery)db.BuyingCompany
                    .FindAll(db.BuyingCompany.u_seller_id == DefaultValues.SellingCompany_GuidStr))
                    .ToArray();
```

In buyingCompanies variable, i am getting below data.

[image]

Comment: And you want to display that in a view? So what's the problem? What have you tried, what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the values by casting it into an

```
IDictionary<string, object>
```

e.g

```
var db = Db.Profiles;

var buyingCompanies = ((SimpleQuery)db.BuyingCompany
                .FindAll(db.BuyingCompany.u_seller_id ==  DefaultValues.SellingCompany_GuidStr))
                .ToArray();

IDictionary<string, object> dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)buyingCompanies;

IEnumerable<object> values = dict.Select(m => m.Value);
```